# Having 2 CollapsingToolbarLayout that can be expanded / collapsed one after the other

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Is there a way to have 2 CollapsingToolbarLayouts (one below the other) that can be expanded / collapsed one after the other ?

Let's take this image as an example :

[image]

The section 1 and 2 are two CollapsingToolbarLayouts (and each one contains a Toolbar I suppose), and the section 3 is a list (a RecyclerView) that can be scrolled.

The user can scroll on the section 3, and it will collapse the section 1. Once the section 1 is fully collapsed, it will collapse the section 2. Once the 2 layouts are collapsed, the user can continue to scroll on the list.

If the user scrolls in the other direction, he will first have to reach the top of the list, and then if he continues scrolling, it will expand the section 2, and then expand the section 1 once the section 2 is fully expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it`t too late response, but I found solution that it may help for other developers.
Here is code, that worked as expected:
When user scroll NestedScrollView, the top collapsingContainerFirst will be collapsed and after that, collapsingContainerSecond become collapsed.
Enjoy!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingContainerFirst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/someContainerWithData"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@color/red" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingContainerSecond"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/someContainerWithOtherData"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for: `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` should do the trick.:

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:text="New Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:text="New Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:text="New Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:text="New Button" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarCollapse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:minHeight="190dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
                    android:minHeight="190dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/social"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also, you may want to take a look at: `app:layout_scrollFlags`

**Flags**:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html

Also, having two Toolbars is not a good idea, i think you were looking for `TabLayout`, something like this example:

https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample

Comment: I'm not sure TabLayout is what I need; I need to realize something like that : https://www.dropbox.com/s/yi9nk7b4jg4v813/2a_08.mp4?dl=0 (notice how the 2 bars are collapsed one after the other)

Comment: I mean, something like above example, see the gif: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4e116716b3ddb76b845c5bcb588b6d69b29d4310/687474703a2f2f692e737461636b2e696d6775722e636f6d2f714b6561462e676966 you should be able to add that `Toolbar` (or whatever outside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in this example, it's a `TabLayout`) like this example: https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/app_container_view.xml this is your solution.

Comment: Or you should just add this to your view: `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` if you are using that in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: In the gif you provided, I just see one view being collapsed, not two.

Comment: it was just an example for that `TabLayout`.